# Adding logarithmic lines (increasing and decresing) in ggplot2 scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

i am going a little crazy here and need some help. I am making a figure for a paper and i'd like to draw it entirely in ggplot2 instead of using external software to manually add lines. Basically the final plot looks like this one:

[image]

The problem are the mixing lines you see. I define them as straight lines in the plot and then by transforming the coordinate they should appear curve (basic math transformations). But when I use cord_trans or similar I get them often going the other way.

Here is a reproducible example without data (only the lines)

```
ggplot() +
stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.0028 * x + 0.999860) + xlim(1,2500) +
stat_function(fun = function(x) -0.000380 * x + 1.000019) + xlim(1,2500) +
coord_trans(y = "log10") +
coord_trans(x = "log10")
```

And this is what I get in stead:

[image]

By not transforming X I get this:

[image]

So the top line is going the right way, but it is not asymptotical and the bottom line is in the wrong way.

Any suggestion?

This is a binary linear mixing model between the two in case it is relevant.

Thank you in advance for any help!
D

Comment: The lines in the logarithmic plot you show simply cannot be straight in Cartesian co-ordinates. Take just the top line for example. At an x axis value of 0.2, it has a y axis value of about 1. At an x axis value of 1, the y value is approximately 5. At x = 100, y is close to 8. At x = 1000, y = 8. This curve would be _even more_ asymptotic in Cartesian Co-ordinates, so it's not clear why you think a straight line would form an asymptote here.

Comment: Hi Allan, yes you are correct, its an hyperbola. I thought it was simpler but it is not, its an hyperbola since in the plot x and y are ratios. Should I edit my question?

Comment: Yes please Don!